# Upload and store large files

Tags: open-source, web-apps, file-management

There are commercial file upload services for large files such as sharefile.com or sendfilessecurely.com.

I'd also like to have a large and secure file upload service, but hosted by myself, because I want people to know that the files are directly stored on my server and not on someone else's. Also, I don't want them to agree to additional EULAs of a third party.

It would need to

- run on a LAMP stack (Ubuntu/Debian preferred)
- be open source
- support HTTPS
- single file size > 2GB
- delete files when downloaded
- configurable file retention time

Answer (score 1):

[OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org) might be what you're looking for.

About the desired features "file deletion after download" and "configurable file retention time", I'm not sure they are natively available in OwnCloud, but you might find some third-party code or plugin that does this.

Comment: Those last two requirements might indeed be a little show-stopper here (everything else is covered by ownCloud). I don't remember having seen an extension (aka "ownCloud app") for that – but then, I wasn't explicitely looking for it when I browsed the entire OC library last week. At least such an addon shouldn't be too hard to implement (not that I volunteer for that: I definitely do not ;)

Comment: The >2 GB file size needs config changes: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/admin_manual/configuration/big_file_upload_configuration.html

Comment: It seems to run on LAMP: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/admin_manual/installation/system_requirements.html#supported-platforms

Comment: Claims to be open source, but I could not find a license (yet) that supports this theory: https://owncloud.org/contribute/

Comment: Ok, it's AGPL, but is that page ever linked from within Owncloud itself? https://owncloud.org/contribute/agreement/

Comment: It supports HTTPS: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/admin_manual/configuration_server/harden_server.html#use-https