# Simple file upload HTTP server

Tags: open-source, web-apps, self-hosted, sharing, uploader

I have people that want to send me files ranging from 500MB to 3GB in size. I want a simple server I can setup behind nginx such that they can have a simple file upload interface.

Requirements:

- Simple file upload form
- Ability to run through nginx as reverse-proxy (ability to set a custom listen port is fine)
- Ability to recieve files up to 4GB in size
- Runs on Ubuntu Linux
- Open-source

Would be nice:

- Progress bar on upload form
- Estimated time remaining to complete upload
- Password-protected (if not I can do it in nginx config)
- Limits on total space used and per-file limit
- Stores files on Amazon S3
- Uses Ruby on Rails

Similar to [Upload and store large files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25802/upload-and-store-large-files) but I don't care what language it's in.

I did find [simple-recieve](https://github.com/dash1291/simple-receive) however it seems updates to packages it depends on have broken it and I don't know enough about Node.js to fix it. Project seems to be abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Well I had similar requirements. Ended up using Wordpress with [the file upload plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-upload/). It was simple and quick to set up.

Answer (score 1):

searching for [http upload server](https://github.com/search?q=http%20upload%20server) on github i found

- [Tallguy297/SimpleHTTPServerWithUpload](https://github.com/Tallguy297/SimpleHTTPServerWithUpload)

  - successfully tested on python3
  - unknown support for uploading large files
  - will listen on all interfaces by default, allows to set `--bind <host> <port>` on CLI
- [jfalken/s3_https_upload_portal](https://github.com/jfalken/s3_https_upload_portal)

  - meets the "Stores files on Amazon S3" criterium

more general:

- [nextcloud](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/stable/user_manual/en/files/access_webgui.html)
- [owncloud](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.7/user_manual/files/webgui/sharing.html)

Answer (score 0):

While a bit *bloated* if the only thing you want is uploads, I eventually used [**Nextcloud**](https://nextcloud.com/) for this; You can do this in nextcloud by creating a folder and setting up a share link for that folder with the permissions set to "Upload only" or "Edit".

Zooming out a bit and not technically answering the question, sending files can also be accomplished with [Web Wormhole](https://webwormhole.io/). It uses WebTorrents to establish a P2P connection, which means both "ends" have to be present (the other side must send you the file while you have the webpage open) *but* you don't need to pay a third party for bandwidth or temporary storage (be it with ads&tracking or a monthly fee).